# Undefined function 'fun_name' for input arguments of type 'uint8' when using custom Matlab function in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I am using the matlab engine to call a matlab custom function based on 'imfindcircles' from python. My function is called 'findCircles' and it is saved in the same folder as my python project files.

When I run the code from a stand alone python file, it works as it should.

However, when I include it within a loop, I get the following error: Undefined function 'findCircles' for input arguments of type 'uint8'

This is the code of my function 'findCircles' in matlab:

```
function [circlesCoord] = findCircles(matlab_img, Rmin1, Rmax1, Rmin2, Rmax2)
[centersDark, radiiDark] = imfindcircles(matlab_img,[Rmin1 Rmax1],'ObjectPolarity','dark');
[centersDark1, radiiDark1] = imfindcircles(matlab_img,[Rmin2 Rmax2],'ObjectPolarity','dark');
if isempty(centersDark) && isempty(centersDark1)
   circlesCoord = [0 0 0];
else
    circlesCoord_temp = horzcat(centersDark,radiiDark);
    circlesCoord1_temp = horzcat(centersDark1,radiiDark1);
    circlesCoord = vertcat(circlesCoord_temp,circlesCoord1_temp);
end
```

This is the section of python code where I use the function:

```
for photo in photos:   
    src = cv2.imread(photo, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    src = cv2.GaussianBlur(src, (3, 3), 0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grad_x = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_16S, 1, 0, ksize=5, scale=1, delta=0, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    grad_y = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_16S, 0, 1, ksize=5, scale=1, delta=0, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    abs_grad_x = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_x)
    abs_grad_y = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_y)  
    sobel_img = cv2.addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0)
    grad_pil = img.fromarray(sobel_img)
    matlab_img = matlab.uint8(list(grad_pil.getdata()))
    matlab_img.reshape((grad_pil.size[0], grad_pil.size[1]))
    eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
    circles_mat = eng.findCircles(matlab_img, Rmin1, Rmax1, Rmin2, Rmax2)
    eng.quit()
    circles_py = np.uint16(np.around(np.asarray(circles_mat)))
    circles_py[:, 0], circles_py[:, 1] = circles_py[:, 1], circles_py[:, 0].copy()
```

Ultimately the code returns an image that displays the circles found using the matlab function, the error is returned when the 'findCircles' function is run.

I have tried to convert the image within the matlab function (even though that made little sense considering that the image passed to the function is already converted into a suitable matlab format) but I still get the error. I have checked that the python and matlab files are in the same folder.

Can anyone suggest how I should go about it? And also, why does this code work if I run it outside a loop?

Thanks!